# Return query with text variable

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to return some query, I got there,well, implicit text variable. How could I get what inside it here? Because of it don't understand that `_table_name` is not text but varibale?

Because I got such error

```
ERROR:  "_table_name" relation does not exist 
LINE 1: SELECT DISTINCT "TYPES".type_id FROM "TYPES", _table_name WH...
```

Here is my function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_las_types(_table_num integer)

    RETURNS TABLE(_type int) AS

    $BODY$
    DECLARE
      _table_name text;

    BEGIN
        _table_name:='well_las_data_'||_table_num;

        RETURN QUERY SELECT DISTINCT "TYPES".type_id FROM "TYPES", _table_name WHERE "TYPES".type_id =  _table_name.type_id;
    END;
    $BODY$
    LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Which PostgreSQL version are you using ?

Comment: @Houari one of the last ones. like 9.2 or smth

Comment: You can use the `format` instruction: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-string.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can safetly construct your dynamic query by using the new [format](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-string.html) function (9.1 and greater):

```
return query execute format('SELECT DISTINCT "TYPES".type_id FROM "TYPES", %I WHERE "TYPES".type_id =  %I.type_id;', _table_name,_table_name);
```

You can find other examples [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-QUOTE-LITERAL-EXAMPLE).